# How to get websocket response on server with spring+stomp+sockjs?

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, websocket, stomp, sockjs

In my javascript I create a websocket:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /// Create stomp client over sockJS protocol (see Note 1)
  var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/hello");
  var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

  // callback function to be called when stomp client is connected to server (see Note 2)
  var connectCallback = function() {
    alert("connected!");
    stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:8080/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
      alert(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
  };

  // callback function to be called when stomp client could not connect to server (see Note 3)
  var errorCallback = function(error) {
    // display the error's message header:
    alert(error.headers.toString);
  };

  // Connect as guest (Note 4)
  stompClient.connect("guest", "guest", connectCallback, errorCallback);
  </script>
```

And also I have a simple form(name testWebSocket.jsp) with button and next function:

```
  // function to send message
 function fnSayHi() {
    stompClient.send("/hello", JSON.stringify({ 'name': 'Joe' }));
 }
 ....
 <input onclick="fnSayHi();" type="button">
```

When I click on button in my view, in the console browser we see sending data, (you might see on image) and I want to get sent data websocket and display them in server console(like System.out.println(..))? Thanks.!

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class MessageController {

@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView getBodyPage() throws SQLException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("testWebSocket");
    return modelAndView;
}

@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(String name) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(name);//here!
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + name + "!");
}
}
```

**part of spring-config:**

```
    <!-- WebSocket -->
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/hello">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are several misunderstandings seeing your code:

1. In your first JS, when you subscribe to a destination, the
   destination is not a URL but a destination name. Instead of
   `http://localhost:8080/topic/greetings` you should subscribe to
   `/topic/greetings`.
2. In you second JS (`testWebSocket.jsp`), you are sending a message to
   `/hello` but there's no mapping for such destination, you should
   send it to `/app/hello` instead as `/app` is configured for application
   destinations (these messages will be handled by your controllers).
3. In your last picture (console), it shows the connection is lost,
   your connection URL might be wrong `http://localhost:8080/hello`
   (maybe missing the application name or servlet mapping?).

Check the [Spring WebSocket Chat application](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat)

Comment: Very thank you for your answer, I edited all above, but when I try to connect, in browser console appears next message: _WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/hello' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200_